# Javascript - How can I remove portion of a string and assign it to a variable for manipulation? String is varied

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have an API call that returns "/Date(1425715200000)/" as part of a JSON object.  I need to be able to evaluate this and return the human readable date.  The API documentation is scant at best.  I am not even certain why they don't just store the time in milliseconds as an integer.

Not sure what the best way to convert and evaluate /Date(1425715200000)/ this to output 3/7/15.

Used this to replace the "/" characters.

```
x = x.replace(/\//g,'');
```

Comment: I would probably use a regex to pull the numbers out and pop it into a `new Date(###)`. Something like `new Date(dateStr.match(/\d+/))` might work.

Comment: "evaluate /Date(1425715200000)/ this to output 3/7/15" Where did you find a 3 in your date ???

Comment: @CyrilDD - 1425715200000 evaluates to the 3/7/15

Comment: Oh milliseconds since midnight, 1 Jan 1970 ? Didn't realise since there was also a "15" in the string

Comment: `console.log(new Date(1425715200000).toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add in custom code to parse your time in milliseconds dates and create a new Date() object from it. Then extract the month day and year properties of the date object.

Heads up on the .getMonth as it will return a value from 0-11.

```js
var jsonObj = {
 date :"/Date(1425715200000)/"
}

function parseDateString( dateObjString ){
  var startIndex  = dateObjString.indexOf("(") + 1;
  var endIndex   = dateObjString.indexOf(")");
  var timeInMilli  = dateObjString.substring( startIndex, endIndex);
  var displayDate;
  var date   = new Date();
     date.setTime( timeInMilli );
  
  displayDate = ( date.getMonth() + 1 ) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();

  alert( displayDate );

}

parseDateString( jsonObj.date );
```

Answer (score 0):

With this sample, you will retrieve a `Date` instance that you can display as you want:

```js
var result = "/Date(1425715200000)/";
result = result.replace(/\/Date\((\d*?)\)\//, "$1");
result = new Date(1 * result);
document.getElementById("output").textContent = result;
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to extract the timestamp, then create an instance of the Date class.

```js
var result = {
    date: "/Date(1425715200000)/"
};

var ts, parts = result.date.match(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)\)\//);
if (parts && parts.length == 2) {
    ts = parseInt(parts[1]);
}

if (ts) {
    var date = new Date(ts);
    
    var str = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    console.log(str);
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = str;
}
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more detail to my comment...

```
var test = "\\Date(1425715200000)\\";
var time = test.match(/\d+/)[0];
var intTime = parseInt(time);
var date = new Date(intTime);
console.log(date); // Sat Mar 07 2015 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
console.log((date.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getUTCDate() + "/" + date.getUTCYear()); // 03/07/14
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var dt = new Date(parseInt('/Date(1425715200000)/'));
var month = dt.getMonth()++, date = dt.getDate(), year = dt.getYFulllYear();
console.log(month+'/'+date+'/'+year.substr(2));
```